# Tooltips not working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

i  have a user registration jsp page where i am using a password field and retype password field for user registration and also using a tool tip for password policy and also retype password policy.But this javascript tool tip is not showing properly in internet explorer,it is getting distorted.i am giving upto where i have done.

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="lbl-01"><bean:message key="registrationForm.userLoginPassword"/> <span class="formElementRequired">*</span></label><a href="#" class="tooltip-right" data-tooltip="Password should contain at least one Capital letter, one special character and one  number.And password length should be atleast 8 characters"><img src="/TMLWeb/image/help.png"/></a>
    <html:password property="userLoginPassword" styleId="userLoginPasswordId" styleClass="text" maxlength="100"/>
    <logic:messagesPresent property="userLoginPassword">
        <font color="red"><html:errors property="userLoginPassword" /></font>
    </logic:messagesPresent>
</div>
```

i am using data-tooltip for the tool tip  but not working properly in IE.can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which version of IE -- something we almost always need to know.

In short, `data-tooltip` does nothing in `IE7` and below.

I understand it has some partial support in `IE8` and it should work well in `IE9+`.

There are a few ways of dealing with the issue... the easiest would be a bit of JavaScript that runs at the bottom of the page:

It will copy the tooltip over to the `title` property, which will work for straight text.

The other option is looking for a tooltip library for IE, and that is outside the scope of this question and StackOverflow.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  (function() {
    function fixTooltips(els) {
      for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        var el = els[i];
        var tooltip = el.getAttribute("data-tooltip");
        if (tooltip) {
          el.title = tooltip;
        }
      }
    }

    var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    fixTooltips(els)
  }());
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I am very sorry for not mentioning the version of IE .

Comment: should i write it under <script></script> coz its not working

Comment: Yes, that is a script and should go in `<script>..</script>` tags.

Comment: <script>(function() {
    function fixTooltips(els) {
      for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        var el = els[i];
        var tooltip = el.getAttribute("data-tooltip");
        if (tooltip) {
          el.title = tooltip;
        }
      }
    }

    var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    fixTooltips(els)
  }());</scrip>